# NuGet : using packages in team development

Tags: version-control, nuget

**Scenario**

1. *Computer A* and *Computer B* are on the same solution with an empty project.
2. *Computer A* install *Package p.1.0* and commit changes (with packages.config)
3. *Computer B* get lastest and perform a package restore => both computers have *Package p1.0*
4. *Computer A* do some changes in the project and before commiting, do an Update-Package. *Package p.1.0* updates to *Package p.1.1*
5. *Computer A* commit changes with packages.config
6. *Computer B* is also working and before committing get latest code => packages.config is updated with line *Package p.1.1*

**Problem**

*Computer A* have *Package p1.1* installed. *Computer B* have *Package p1.0* installed and with an Update-Package, nothing changes.

**Questions**

- Am I wrong ?
- If not, how to correct this problem ?

"Do an Update-Package **before** getting code from VCS resolve the problem but it's not a good solution because everyone can forget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When computer B get latest code, there will be reference to 1.1 in packages.config and project files. This package will be installed before next build (if you didn't disabled automatic packages restore). So in this case there are no problems.

Problem could be if Computer B applied changes incompatible with 1.1 version. In this case it will be nice practice run unit tests/test app after merge before push. And continuous integration practice could be very helpful in this case.